# How to compare two strings in assembly language [NASM]

Tags: nasm

I have a school project to finish and I need to write a simple program in assembly language.

I did most of the work but I want to compare the the user input and the string I provide in the code but it just doesn't want to work.

I have read this post -> [Comparing variables in NASM Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774374/comparing-variables-in-nasm-assembly)

I do understand that eax and ebx registers are 64 bit and they have "garbage" in them so they are never equal, but I have no idea how to fix that in my case as applying lower bit register throws out an error.

Here is the code:

```
section .data
    text1 db "What is your name? "
    text2 db "Nice to meet you, "
    text3 db "I already know you Dawid!"
    toName db "Dawid"
    
section .bss
    userName resb 16
    
section .text
    global _start
    
_start

    call _printText1
    call _getUserName
    call _compareName
    
    mov rax, 60 ;Pass the exit code to stop the program
    mov edi, 0 ;Set the error code to 0 so the program knows there is no error
    syscall ;run the commands
    
_printText1
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text1
    mov rdx, 19
    syscall
    ret
    
_printUserName
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, userName
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret
    
_getUserName
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, userName
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret
    
_compareName
    mov eax, userName
    cmp eax, toName
    je _printAnswer1
    jne _printAnswer2
    
_printAnswer1
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text3
    mov rdx, 25
    syscall
    ret
    
_printAnswer2
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text2
    mov rdx, 18
    syscall
    
    call _printUserName
    ret
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're comparing addresses, not the contents at those addresses. You'll have to write a loop that reads characters from both locations and compares them (or use `repe cmpsb`).

Comment: @Michael Thank you.